# C++: Undefined reference to 'NameSpace::Class::Constructor'

Tags: c++, class, undefined-reference

I'm starting with C++ and I'm trying to create a class program, however, when I try to run it appears the error: C++: Undefined reference to 'NameSpace::Class::Constructor. The code is shown below:

**Header for ClassA:**

```cpp
//ClassA.h
#ifndef CLASSA_H 
#define CLASSA_H
#include <string>

namespace ClassANameSpace
{
    class ClassA
    {
    private:
        std::string attribute1;
        double attribute2;

    public:
        ClassA();
        ClassA(std::string pAttribute1, double pAttribute2);

        void setClassA(std::string pAttribute1, double pAttribute2);
        
        std::string getAttribute1() { return attribute1; }
        double getAttribute2() { return attribute2; }

    };
}

#endif
```

**Class A:**

```cpp
//ClassA.cpp
#include "ClassA.h"
using namespace ClassANameSpace;

ClassA::ClassA()
{

}

ClassA::ClassA(std::string pAttribute1, double pAttribute2)
{
    setClassA(pAttribute1, pAttribute2);
}

void ClassA::setClassA(std::string pAttribute1, double pAttribute2)
{
    attribute1 = pAttribute1;
    attribute2 = pAttribute2;
}
```

**Main:**

```cpp
// main.cpp
#include <iostream>
#include "ClassA.h"
using namespace std;
using namespace ClassANameSpace;

int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    ClassA classA ("string", 1.0);
    return 0;
}
```

When I try to run it appears: undefined reference to `ClassANameSpace::ClassA::ClassA(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits, std::allocator >, double)'

Someone can guide me to undestand what is going on?

Comment: Please show how do you compile your code.

Comment: And offtopic, but what's the point of adding namespaces if you abolish it in every file with `using namespace`?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is an undefined reference/unresolved external symbol error and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12573816/what-is-an-undefined-reference-unresolved-external-symbol-error-and-how-do-i-fix)

Comment: How are you compiling this? I just tried with: `g++ -std=c++11 main.cpp ClassA.cpp` and it compiled and ran fine.

Comment: I am using Visual Studio Code and I dont know how to compile it correctly, however, now I im trying with codeblocks and it works. Someone knows where can I look for the right way to compile in VSC? 
Thank you very much!

Comment: @SnowArtz Please update your question now that you know more.